# SideBar and Dashboard with React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to connect my sidebar to dashboard. Everytime I click on an icon in the sidebar I want to sidebar to stays the same  but dashboard to change. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsBnN.jpg I am having a problem with the rendering. When I click on the Sound Icon Sidebar does not stay as you can see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bieh2.jpg

```
import React from 'react'
import './SystemSidebar.css'
import SoundIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Computer';
import ComputerIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Computer';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sound from './Sound';
import Computer from './Computer;
const SystemSidebar=()=> {
    return (
    <div className='system'>
       <div className="sidebar">
           <Link to='Sound'><VolumeUpIcon /></Link>
              <h4> Sound</h4>   
                 <Link to='Computer'><ComputerIcon /></Link>
                   <h4> Computer</h4>   
                      </div>
                         </div>
 

import React,{Component} from 'react'
import Sound from './Sound';
import Computer from './Computer';
import SystemSidebar from './SystemSidebar';
class MainSystem extends Component {

    render(){
      return (
        <div className="MAIN">
          <BrowserRouter>
            <SystemSidebar />
              <Switch>
                 <Route exact path="/" component={SystemSidebar} />
                 <Route exact path="/Sound" component={Sound}/>
                 <Route exact path="/Computer" component={Computer}/>
               </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div> 
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you post the code from two separate .js files into this code block? Your `SystemSidebar` function is missing some closing parenthesis/brackets and this code has multiple duplicate imports/incorrect paths if all this code lives in the same file.

Other than that, you're rendering `SystemSidebar` twice when at the root URL. You want a component for some type of home/welcome page at this route, not the sidebar:

`<Route exact path="/" component={SystemSidebar} />`

Please post complete code in separate code blocks if the code is in separate files.

Comment: SystemSidebar has its own parent which is                                                                                                                   `const Settings=()=> {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>text</h3>
<div className='sett'>
            <Link to='SystemSidebar'><ComputerIcon /></Link>
            
          
           
            


</div>
        </div>
    )
}`

Comment: @tekila12 I see you're new, please take some time to read this document so the community can better answer your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Code examples should be Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable. Always post complete examples of components/modules. There is not enough information here to give an informed answer.